# Special URL for language selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, cookies

Just a simple question, I was wondering why some websites have something like "?lang=EN" in their URL after selecting a language? Is it because their html file or folder containing it is named "?lang=EN", or some other code that does this? I'd like to set the URL like that for my website (has 2 languages). Currently I have folder structure like this:

Language selection: D:/media/index.html

EN site: D:/media/en/index.html

CN site: D:/media/cn/index.html

Files for the website: D:/media/site

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's because they often have a content management system where the content isn't stored in files necessarily, but in a database. The `lang=en` is a GET variable from the URL that they retrieve in, for example, PHP, to display the correct content. In your case, however, you can just redirect the user if they click `EN` or `CN` to the appropriate locations, in your case, `/en/index.html` and `/cn/index.html`.

Comment: Suggest "... in PHP ..." ==> "... in, for example, PHP ..."

Answer (score 0):

PHP uses `$_GET` to get value from variables from the URL.It gets the value from that `LANG` variable and then it selects all from a file where are stored all the words in different languages or from the database

You don't need to copy every file and then translate it.

Search for php dynamic pages tutorial in your case. I found [**THIS**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqPp8EzjCMY).

P.S. PHP is one from many ways to do this.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention PHP. Server-side could have any one of a dozen other things.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, anything after the file extension ( .html ) is a server side function.

The ? is a function for PHP and adds variables to the super global GET array ( in the form: ?variable=value&variable2=value2 ) that is directed to from another page and from that point many things can be done with the data.

Sites that use the ?lang=EN are probably programmed to print out the chunks of text needed on the single page in the places and languages required. Though it is possible using this method to redirect to a language specific directory.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The OP doesn't mention PHP. Server-side could have any one of a dozen other things.

Answer (score 0):

The url you see at the address bar, whatever comes after `"?"` is called "QueryString" and with libraries on the server side (based on the developing platform that website is made on) you can access the values. For instance the value of `"lang"` can be equal to `"EN"` or `"CN"` etc.

By the way you can have some http handlers to rewrite the requested url and get your parameters through the url that physically doesn't exists. Like the one you mentioned, "http://yoursite.com/**en**/default.whatever". I myself prefer this way but as you requested you should use some server side libraries to access the query string values and choose the language of the content you wanna send to client.

Also as one solution that once I used, you can also use some translation service (like translate.google.com) client libraries and call it at client side with jquery or even javascript and translate all the texts on page load. Although it's damn fast in action, it has some issues you will see.

Hope it helps.